# insertSubview belowSubview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't want just the syntax because I've already got it from apple's developer site and I don't know what but I'm doing something wrong. What I need is an actual calling of this function.

Can anyone tell me how to write below Obj-C code in **swift**?

```
[self.view insertSubview:VC1.view belowSubview: VC2.view];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Swift you can do it like this:

```
self.view.insertSubview(VC1.view, belowSubview: VC2.view)
```